# is there a way to make my music discord bot saves the volume setting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

When I play music, and I set the volume to 20% for example, when the bot leaves the voice channel, and then I play another music, the volume goes back to 100%, and I have to set it again manually to 20% again.

I want to make my bot save the volume I set. Is there any way to do that?

Here's my code:

```js
 } else if (command === "volume" || command === "vol") {
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send("I'm sorry, but you need to be in a voice channel to set a volume!");
        if (!serverQueue) return message.channel.send("There is nothing playing");
        if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send(`The current volume is: **\`${serverQueue.volume}%\`**`);
        if (isNaN(args[1]) || args[1] > 100) return message.channel.send("Volume only can be set in a range of **\`1\`** - **\`100\`**");
        serverQueue.volume = args[1];
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.setVolume(args[1] / 100);
        return message.channel.send(`I set the volume to: **\`${args[1]}%\`**`);
```

Comment: Use some sort of database, see [the official discord.js guide for database utilisation](https://discordjs.guide/keyv/#installation)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The suggested database solution seem a bit overkill for the task. Have you considered using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) ?

After configuring dotenv, you could for example declare a VOLUME variable in the `.env` at the root of your app: `VOLUME=20`

Then, you could access this value everywhere in your application. It seems you're using `serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.setVolume()` method to set the volume.

You would now do `serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.setVolume(process.env.VOLUME)` before playing audio to ensure the correct value is always set (in this context, `process.env.VOLUME === 20`)

Now, the function that changes this value would become as simple as `process.env.VOLUME = args[1] / 100`. That will update the "VOLUME" variable: next time you reference `process.env.VOLUME`, it will have the new value, so it's a good idea to keep your input validation for `args[1]` (should still be a number in the 1-100 range).

With this method, when you exit the process (Ctrl + C) and relaunch it, the `VOLUME` variable will be reinitialized with the value you declared in your `.env` file (`20` in this example)

I believe this solution is lighter and more appropriate for your need, as you should already be using `dotenv` to protect your Discord API key.

But if you have a lot of other informations to persist aside that `VOLUME` variable, the solution mentioned by aDeveloper (`Keyv` extra dependency) may be better suited.

[Example of discord.js bot using dotenv](https://github.com/TheRealBarenziah/jdr9000/blob/master/index.js#L1), in case you need an example to configure yours.

[Here](https://github.com/TheRealBarenziah/jdr9000/blob/master/commands/gandalf.js#L15) you can see an hardcoded volume value: if you clone the repo, add `VOLUME=50` in the `.env` file and replace my hardcoded `0.5` by `process.env.VOLUME / 100`, it will work exactly the same.

/EDIT

Answering your comment, I'll try to resume the chronological steps you must take:

- install `dotenv` module as explained in their README
- create a `.env` file at the root of our application
- in that file, declare a VOLUME variable: `VOLUME=20`
- put `require("dotenv").config();` in the entry point of your app, as I shown in my [example](https://github.com/TheRealBarenziah/jdr9000/blob/master/index.js#L1)
- launch your bot and make sure `dotenv` works properly by putting a `console.log("VOLUME = ", process.env.VOLUME);` in whatever command you can easily call via Discord
- call that command: you should see your console.log in your terminal.
- If `VOLUME = undefined`, you missed something in your setup. Reread their README, rewatch my example and you should figure it out.
- If `VOLUME = 20`, you're good, it means the VOLUME variable has been initialized and now lives within your application.
- You can now access this variable (process.env.VOLUME) everywhere in your application.
- You can access its value with `process.env.VOLUME` as you just did with the console.log. The only difference now is that you pass this value to the method you're using to set volume (which is `serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.setVolume()` from what I've read), instead of the console.log() method.
- You can also change its value doing `process.env.VOLUME = newValue`. Doing that will assign `newValue` to your VOLUME variable.
- Next time you access `process.env.VOLUME`, it will have the last value you've assigned to it: that's how you'll "save the volume setting".
- The VOLUME variable will exist with the value you've set, as long as your application runs.
- If you kill and restart your bot, `process.env.VOLUME` will be equal to 20 once more. That's because you declared so in the `.env` file.
- This is what `require("dotenv").config()` method does, and why it should be called at the very start of your application: this method will read your `.env` file, and assign the values to `process.env.YOURCHOSENKEYWORDS`.
- Note: if you want the last volume set to be persisted even if you restart your bot, this solution won't do, and you'll have to either write & read a local JSON file, or take the database route suggested by the first comment

Once you've got this, the next step will be to declare your Discord API key inside your `.env` file instead of hardcoding it. But that will be for another day/question

Comment: like this?

```serverQueue.volume = args[1];
    serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.setVolume(process.env.VOLUME);
    return message.channel.send(`I set the volume to: **\`${args[1]}%\`**`);
```

Comment: I don't really understand. I tried what u told me. but it doesn't work

Comment: can u help me, explain which part I should change?

Comment: I detailed my answer

Comment: I tried a lot of things to make it work, with ur answer as the guide..

Comment: but really sorry. I still don't get it

Comment: can u change the code for me? so that I know where I did wrong

here's my code:
https://github.com/Haque13/BarbaraBot/blob/master/index.js

Comment: I've also added ```VOLUME=20``` to my .env file

Comment: Made you a [PR](https://github.com/Haque13/BarbaraBot/pull/1). Please follow the tutorial I provided before asking anyone else to look at your code ;)

Comment: thank u very much. now I know where I did wrong, I changed my ```serverQueue.volume``` value to ```process.env.VOLUME``` instead of removing it and replace it with ```process.env.VOLUME = args[1]```. and also I found that ```serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.setVolume(args[1] / 100)``` shouldn't be removed, it'll make the bot unable to change it's volume. thank u very much

Comment: Happy you figured it out. Don't forget to validate my answer :)